# Can run Angular app from local computer but not from local server

Tags: angularjs, server, ecstatic

I can start and run my Angular app fine from my local computer. But I have never run it on a server before.

I have tried uploading it to the server. On the server I type the following to start it:

```
http-server
```

Then I visit `http://serverip:8080/`. Instead of seeing my app I see:

```
Index of /

(-rw-rw-r--)    847B    app.js
(-rw-rw-r--)    748B    index.htm

Node.js v0.10.25/ ecstatic server running @ 195.189.182.160:8080
```

What is missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

`ecstatic` is a static file server. It's not set up to be a web server by default, even though it can work that way. When you do run it as a web server, certain standard options in most web servers - like treating a request for `/path/` as a request for `/path/index.htm` - are disabled by default.

You need to enable `opts.autoIndex`. [The package readme tells you how to do that](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ecstatic#opts-autoindex). In your case, it means editing `http-server` or the `.js` file that it fires off; it's hard to say from what you have posted.

Comment: That sounds complicated. Is any other web server simpler to run Angular from for a beginner? I'm at the stage where I need a step by step tutorial to follow to succeed.

Comment: @user1283776 You can use whatever you want - Apache, nginx, a simple node.js listener, or whatever. You will have to run it on top of something, however. Software recommendations and recommendations for tutorials are off-topic for SO, but you should have no problem finding them in a search engine. You might also look at [this question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17947084/2057919).

Comment: Only node.js, only single language for both -ends